# How to disable the default behavior of an Anchor in jQuery Mobile (iOS)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building an app for iPhone and iPad using PhoneGap and jQM

```
<div class="ui-block-a">
   <a id="btnLink" href="#pageID" data-role="button"></a>
</div>
```

and it functions fine, but when I run it on the device (didn't try the simulator) and press a long press, I get the default iPhone menu for a link in a normal browser to open or copy the link.

how can I disable this default feature in my app?

I tried these with no success:

```
$("a").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // long press menu still apear
});


$("a").bind('click',function(event) {
console.log(['preventingclick',event.type]);
event.preventDefault(); // long press menu still apear
});
```

if I bind on 'taphold' I still see the menu on a long press, but after I click cancel I see the console log: ["preventing long press","taphold"]

```
$("a").bind('taphold', function(event) {
console.log(['preventing long press',event.type]);
event.preventDefault(); // long press menu still apear
});
```

if I use delegate on 'taphold' event like this:

```
$("a").delegate('taphold', function(event) {
console.log(['preventing long press',event.type]);
event.preventDefault();
});
```

will fix the problem, but I can't attach any events anymore, so non of my buttons will work after that.

```
$('#btnLink').bind("click", function() {
$.mobile.changePage('mypage', 'slide'); // won't fire any more because of the delegate before
});
```

I know that delegate will apply on all elements now and in the future, but I think I am getting close to the answer, but not yet.

Thanks in advance

[image: Anchor long press menu on iPhone]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ok got it to work,

I had to combine both code fixes, CSS and JavaScript

so in my CSS I did this:

```
body { -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; }
a { -webkit-user-select: none !important; }
```

in my JavaScript did this:

```
function onBodyLoad() {
  $("a").bind('taphold', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
 });
}
```

and now all the links are disabled, but if I attach an event to any of them it will work with no problem

THanks all

Comment: does `taphold` require jQuery mobile?

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the events fired by JQM here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html. You want to handle the "taphold" event.

**EDIT**
Soon after posting this I ended up seeing the same problem in my app! I found that adding this style, similar to what @chrisben suggested fixes it:

```
body {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
```

I don't have any form elements on my app so I don't know about those but links and buttons all work perfectly fine with this style added.

Comment: Tried preventing default on tabhold using bind, did not work
if I use delegate, all my click events and buttons will stop working, even the ones that I attached events to them after, wont work, I guess I am getting close, but not the final answer yet, thanks

Answer (score 7):

When you do $('a').click( .. ) you're only processing the 'click' event. Here it's a different event and actually a system event for iOS that you cannot handle in javascript.

So you'll have to disable this feature completely from your webapp if you don't want it.

Try the following:

```
<script>
document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = 'none';
</script>
```

Or in your CSS:

```
a[data-role=button] {
    -webkit-user-select: none!important;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, actually I just tried this and it did not work, still getting the menu in my app on a long press...

Comment: The javascript does work.  Replace documentElement with the element you need to disable the styling for.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way to get this to work on iPhone is to disable the webkit touch styles:

```
document.getElementById('your element id').style.webkitTouchCallout = 'none';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css">
 *:not(input):not(textarea) {
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
 -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
}       
</style>

**If you want Disable only anchor button tag use this.**
 a {-webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
 }
```