# Preventing default context menu on longpress / longclick in mobile Safari (iPad / iPhone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

For a website I want to show a custom context menu when a user "longpresses" the screen. I've created a [jQuery Longclick](https://github.com/pisi/Longclick) listener in my code to show a custom context menu. The context menu is displayed, but the iPad's default context menu is also displayed! I tried to prevent this by adding a [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to the event in my listener, but this does not work:

```
function showContextMenu(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // code to show custom context menu
}

$("#myId").click(500, showContextMenu);
```

**Questions**

1. Can you prevent the iPad's default context menu to show?
2. Can it by done using the jQuery Longclick plugin?

---

The Longclick plugin has some specific handling for the iPad (assuming by this snippet of [it's source code](https://github.com/pisi/Longclick/blob/master/jquery.longclick.js)):

```
if (!(/iphone|ipad|ipod/i).test(navigator.userAgent)){
  $(this)
  .bind(_mousedown_, schedule)
  .bind([_mousemove_, _mouseup_, _mouseout_, _contextmenu_].join(' '), annul)
  .bind(_click_, click)
}
```

So I assume this answers my second question (assuming the plugin used the correct event).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks to JDandChips for [pointing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12424987/880619) me to the solution. It works perfectly in combination with the longclick plugin. For documentation sake I'll post my own answer to show what I did.

HTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://raw.github.com/pisi/Longclick/master/jquery.longclick-min.js"></script>

<p><a href="http://www.google.com/">Longclick me!</a></p>
```

The Javascript already was OK:

```js
function longClickHandler(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("body").append("<p>You longclicked. Nice!</p>");
}

$("p a").longclick(250, longClickHandler);
```

The fix was to add these rules to the style sheet:

```css
body { -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; }
a { -webkit-user-select: none !important; }
```

[Disabled context menu **example**](http://jsfiddle.net/z9ZNU/53/).

Comment: This is only a solution for longclick on anchors. If you have an input area, text area or some other form of content editor this does not solve the problem of the default context menu appearing.

Answer (score 22):

```
<style type="text/css">
*:not(input):not(textarea) {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
}       
</style>
```

If you want disable only anchor button tag use this:

```
a {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
}
```

Comment: Applying this globally to all links is a bad practice on mobile websites.

Comment: This works on iphone ios9.  My father often longclicks on a listview item and this css disables the popup.

Comment: I highly recommend against the star selector and would even label it an anti-pattern in this context. Shutting off a basic browser feature across the board will likely cause you problems down the road. This hatchet-for-a-scalpel type approach is what makes projects go downhill.
Option two, however, is acceptable, as long as you do it in targeted scenarios. That's just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 9):

A quick css solution:

```
html {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

user-select disables highlighting text/areas.
touch-callout disables context menu popup.

Comment: i want the user to still select, but i dont want the context menu to popup.... when i removed -webkit-user-select: none;, it still shows the context menu for me :(

Comment: Why not `html { display: none !important; }` ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me on iPad. Seems impossible to disable Safari longpress on IPad

Answer (score 9):

No need to use JavaScript, It can be performed using css.

For disabling context menu only for images,
Use

```css
img{
-webkit-touch-callout: none !important; 
 -webkit-user-select: none !important; }
```

If we need to disable context menu for particular classes,
Use

```css
.className{-webkit-touch-callout: none !important; 
-webkit-user-select: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an iPad so couldn't test a solution, but I did come across a similar question, which was resolved. I don't know if it will be of any help to you, but here is the link: [How to disable the default behavior of an Anchor in jQuery Mobile (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714868/how-to-disable-the-default-behavior-of-an-anchor-in-jquery-mobile-ios)

Answer (score 2):

None of the CSS answers worked for me.

The only thing that worked for me:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {e.preventDefault()});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to rely on `-webkit-` properties.

If your link is a Javascript call, it's as easy as removing the `href="void(0)"` completely! Your `ontouchend` or `onclick` attributes will still work. If you want the link to look original, add this css:

```
a .originalLink { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer; }
```

This will run a lot smoother, especially when there are hundreds of links in the page.

You can also extend this to "real" page-links at the cost of SEO loss:

```
<a class="originalLink" onclick="location.href='http://mylink';">Real URL Link</a>
```

Not exactly good practice for most websites, but for a *specific* mobile-friendly situation (mobile web app) this can be crucial.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

This github repository work for me. In my case I write an iPad app using UIWebView.

https://github.com/vaidik/jquery-longpress