# Disable context menu after long tap on link on safari iphone

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, safari

How to disable context menu after long tap on link without preventDefault() on safari iphone?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304012/preventing-default-context-menu-on-longpress-longclick-in-mobile-safari-ipad

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none
```

http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-touch-callout