# disabling mobile long press on react-router Link tags

Tags: reactjs, anchor, react-router, long-press, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a progressive web app and hope the users add it to their home screens which launches the app in standalone mode(full screen without browser address bar).   However, since i'm using lots of react-router **Link** component (which i believe is just an anchor tag)  any time i long press on a component wrapped in **Link** a menu pops up with options i.e copy link address...open in chrome etc.  Is there a way to disable this from happening, because I don't want users leave the standalone mode and open the link in browser.

Comment: You might want to try disabling the event using [javascript or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12472477/5995040). I have tried it in a react-router but you can try it since its a web app. Setting the `-webkit-touch-callout` to `none` disables the callout from a target such as a link, and `-webkit-user-select` to make text unselectable. Hope this helps.

Comment: I recommend you don't. Users expect long press to behave a specific way and will get pissed off if mess with it. They already decided to add your apps icon to their homescreen, let them open links in a Chrome if they choose to.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use<\Link>, use createBrowserHistory.push function on custom component instead. <\Link> implements by <\a>, user-select: 'none' will not work on <\a>.

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color:  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
```

this should works