# Ionic framework makes 'open in new tab' option unavailable for ng-href in ios devices

Tags: javascript, html, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to achieve a functionality in mobile devices where *tap* would open 'codepen.io'(handled by ng-click) and *tap and hold* would open the context menu with 'Open In New Tab' option in it, which leads to 'stackoverflow.com'(handled by ng-href)

Here is the code:
HTML:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainController as main">
      <a ng-href="https://stackoverflow.com/" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); main.getUrl()">The Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Controller (AngularJS 1.4.9):

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainController', MainController);


  function MainController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.getUrl = function() {
      window.location.replace('https://codepen.io');
    }
  }

})();
```

`$event.preventDefault();` was added to `ng-click` to prevent '`href`' from overriding `ng-click` on *tap* and loading the wrong url.

I have issue achieving the functionality in ios devices, where no context menu was opened on '*tap and hold*' in ios devices before Iphone X.

If you remove the ionic framework source from the head tag, the code works in ios devices. However, I am using ionic framework for my angularJS application. So it can't be avoided.

Is there a way to achieve 'open In new tab' option to be available in ios devices with ionic still there?

Here is the codepen link : [demo](https://codepen.io/NightShade1993/pen/RqYOVm)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304012/preventing-default-context-menu-on-longpress-longclick-in-mobile-safari-ipad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, *-webkit-touch-callout* property may be *none*. 
Rmove that or add the following style, will resolve this issue

```
body {-webkit-touch-callout: default !important;}
```