# hammer.js and preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hammer.js

js to also support touch-gestures. I'm bagging my head about prevent default actions. when I set `event.preventDefault` or `event.gesture.preventDefault()` or even apply parameter `{prevent_defaults: true }` on hammer it just triggers default action on the anchor. How can I prevent that and/or what am I doing wrong?!

Code snippet;

```
function initializeNavigation() {
    $("nav").hammer({prevent_defaults: true }).on("tap", "a", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.gesture.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this.hash);
        scrollToTarget(target, 1200);
        // if there is an open detailItem then close it.
        if (detailItemOpen) {
            $("div." + detailItemOpen).slideUp();
        }
    })

    if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 767px)'))  {
        initializeMobileMenuAndSetButton();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although not quite a duplicate, this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714868/how-to-disable-the-default-behavior-of-an-anchor-in-jquery-mobile-ios

Comment: I don't get your answer because it also happens in Firefox. It has something to do with Hammer.js and the events. When I used just the click-events everything worked correct on devices with a mouse.

Comment: True, long discussion about it here. It is about stopPropagation(), but applies to preventDefault() too: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/issues/237

Comment: Aha okay. I read the topic. So a tap isn't yhe same as a click-event. That's why still default behaviour, click on anchor, is still being triggered. I could use the opted solution. I bind a second on-method .on("click", funtion(event) { event.preventDefault()}

Comment: Your last comment should be the accepted answer myradon ;)

Answer (score 1):

Considering Hammer 2.0+ `event.gesture` is no longer and Event, but a simple Object.

`event.gesture.srcEvent` will not be the proper event to stopPropagation on, so it will not work.

If you are using the `tap` event, and want to prevent click/taps on the document you can do something like this. 
We need to create a global tap handler that will replace the original methods `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`

```js
function createHandler(event) {
  return {
    isHandled: false,
    _shouldStopPropagation: false,
    _shoulePreventDefault: false,
    stopPropagation: event.stopPropagation.bind(event),
    preventDefault: event.preventDefault.bind(event),
  }
}


function handleEvent(handler, node) {
  let clickHandler; 


  if (!handler.isHandled) {
    handler.isHandled = true;
    document.addEventListener('click', clickHandler = (event)=> {
      if (handler._shouldStopPropagation) {
        handler.stopPropagation();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      
      if (handler._shoulePreventDefault) {
        handler.preventDefault();
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      document.removeEventListener('click', clickHandler, true);
    }, true);
  }
}


// Create a global tap Event so we can replace the original functions
document.addEventListener('tap', (event)=> {
  let handler = createHandler(event);

  event.stopPropagation = function() {
    handler._shouldStopPropagation = true;
    handleEvent(handler);
  };
  event.preventDefault  = function() {
    handler._shoulePreventDefault = true;
    handleEvent(handler);
  }
}, true);

// Now we can use it.
document.addEventListener('tap', (event)=> {
  /* If you want to prevent Default */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* If you want to stop propagation */
  event.stopPropagation();

  /* If you want to do both */
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: What are all the possible events that I might/should add listeners to and stop propagation on?  "tap" doesn't even seem to be an actual event that document can listen to...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also try `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.gesture.stopPropagation()`.
But it seems that Hammer gives that method : `event.gesture.stopDetect()` for a similar case.

source: https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/Event-delegation-and-how-to-stopPropagation---preventDefaults

Comment: It's old but think stopPropagation isn't solving anything. Click and tap events should bubble to the same DOM-element the handler have been bind to. If you use stoppropagation it doesn't bubble further up the DOM.