# How to disable the copy & past text functionality for ANDROID as well as IOS which is coming after long press on screen in Phonegap application

Tags: android, ios, cordova

[image]Phone Gap issue-

How to disable the default text copy-paste functionality for ANDROID as well as IOS which is coming after long press on screen in Phonegap application.

I referred [How to disable the default behavior of an Anchor in jQuery Mobile (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714868/how-to-disable-the-default-behavior-of-an-anchor-in-jquery-mobile-ios), but it is not feasible solution. I want code in config.xml file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
**Use below code:**
<style type="text/css">
*:not(input):not(textarea) {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
}       
</style>

**If you want Disable only anchor button tag use this.**
a {-webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in main Activity**
on the MainActivity where you are doing  loadUrl(launchUrl);
paste After oncreate method

```
 super.appView.getView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

this will prevent copy on long press