# Cordova: How to disable double tap COPY/PASTE options in Android?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I need to secure my cordova app by disabling the copy/paste options throughout the app. I found the following code which works perfectly fine (i.e. disables the copy/paste options if we touch and hold on any input texts).

```
public class CopyPasteDisabler extends CordovaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);

        webView.getView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                 return true;
             }
         });

    }
}
```

But the copy/paste options are still showing up when I double tap on any input field texts. I need to disable that too. How could we achieve that?

Thanks

***UPDATE 1:***

Just figured out a way to disable those options on double tap using `GestureDetector`. But those options are still showing up on 3 taps. So, the problem still exists there. The new code looks like as follows:

```
public class CopyPasteDisabler extends CordovaPlugin {

    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CordovaInterface cordova, CordovaWebView webView) {
        super.initialize(cordova, webView);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(cordova.getActivity(), new DoubleTapGestureDetector());

        webView.getView().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });

        webView.getView().setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private class DoubleTapGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can disable double tap from within Javascript like this :

```
$("body").nodoubletapzoom();
```

Comment: Can you try this ?
 $('#someid').dblclick(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
 }); where someid is <li id="someid">

Answer (score 0):

There is some nice answer given by a guy name **Narsingh Tomar** on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481254/how-to-disable-the-copy-past-text-functionality-for-android-as-well-as-ios-whi)

according to this you can use

```
`<style type="text/css">
*:not(input):not(textarea) {
  -webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
}       
</style>

**If you want Disable only anchor button tag use this.**
a {-webkit-user-select: none; /* disable selection/Copy of UIWebView */
   -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* disable the IOS popup when long-press on a link */
 }`
```

**EDIT**

```
* {
   -webkit-user-select: none;
}
```

the above code work for me in all cases. try it