# MobileFirst iOS app longpress gesture trigger a system context menu

Tags: html, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I've found that while holding on any anchor links of our MobileFirst iOS app (more than 2 or 3 seconds), iOS will trigger its build-in menu which shows **internal path** of current html page.

I don't know if this feature is related to PhoneGap, cordova, MobileFirst or HTML5 apps but can I disable it when users hold on anchors ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IBM MobileFirst app at the end of the day is made up of web code, so just like in Mobile Safari where after long-pressing you'd get a menu of some sort this is the case here as well.

There are many results on a google search how to disable the long-press context menu in iOS. See one such result here: [Preventing default context menu on longpress / longclick in mobile Safari (iPad / iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304012/preventing-default-context-menu-on-longpress-longclick-in-mobile-safari-ipad)

Attempt to add this code (with proper modifications) in your app.
If it doesn't work for you, create an isolated demo app that this can be reproduced in and provide it for debugging.

Comment: So this solution should be a best practise of all web apps not only the WL app since most developers and users don't like the context menu feature. And also this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714868/how-to-disable-the-default-behavior-of-an-anchor-in-jquery-mobile-ios works great, too.