# Mousedown and mouseup on ios acts different than on safari and firefox on mac

Tags: javascript, ios, css

I'm adding two eventListener()'s to a html button so I can detect a long press. It works on safari and firefox on mac but when I open the same webpage in ios on an iphone/ipad or in a simulator the copy/paste popup menu appears.

I found [Preventing default context menu on longpress / longclick in mobile Safari (iPad / iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304012/preventing-default-context-menu-on-longpress-longclick-in-mobile-safari-ipad) and [How to disable the default behavior of an Anchor in jQuery Mobile (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714868/how-to-disable-the-default-behavior-of-an-anchor-in-jquery-mobile-ios).

The popup was solved adding the following to css:

```
html {
    -webkit-user-select: none !important;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
```

If the button is held x ms. it shall perform some function. When I print mouse_delta in an alert message it shows 2 (ms.) even though I hold down the button a few seconds. So it might be a powersaving feature in ios.

Javascript (partial):

```
var hometeam_goal = document.getElementById("add_goal_hometeam");

hometeam_goal.addEventListener("mousedown", function homegoal_md (event) {
    mouse_start = Date.now();
}

hometeam_goal.addEventListener("mouseup", function homegoal_mu (event) {
    mouse_delta = Date.now() - mouse_start;
    if (mouse_delta < foo) {
        <do something>
    }
}
```

How can I work around this on ios?

regards
Claus